# Kendo DropDownListFor not s ending info to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

This is baffling. In one of my MVC models, `Project`, I have two properties which both save the IDs for other models, like so.

```
public class Project
{
    ...
    public int PlatformID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I use a custom editor in which I edit these fields with a kendo dropdown, using their respective names and IDs as text and value fields.

```
<div class="col-md-11 details-item">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PlatformID, new { @class = "col-md-4 details-label" })
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.PlatformID)
        .Name("PlatformID")
        .DataValueField("ID")
        .DataTextField("PlatformName")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Platforms"])
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "col-md-7 details-editor" })
    )
</div>
<div class="col-md-11 details-item">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DepartmentID, new { @class = "col-md-4 details-label" })
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartmentID)
        .Name("DepartmentID")
        .DataValueField("ID")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Departments"])
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "col-md-7 details-editor" })
    )
</div>
```

What's crazy is that `PlatformID` saves perfectly, but `DepartmentID` does not even get sent to the controller. If `DepartmentID` is the only thing I change while editing, it does not even register a change has been made. Otherwise, it gets sent as default 0.

The `Department` class is insanely simple.

```
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Department Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`PlatformID` is essentially identical. Maybe I'm missing something stupid, or maybe there is evil afoot. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Not related, but remove `.Name("PlatformID")` and  `.Name("DepartmentID")` (the `DropDownListFor()` method already adds the correct `name` and `id` attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer - turns out having a DropDown in an editor template does not work if the item is nullable! So I just changed `public int? DepartmentID`to `public int DepartmentID`in my Project model, and life was good again.